# Code run automatically on changing cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am trying to run some VBA script to run automatically when I change a cell value automatically. I do have the script int he Worksheet and not a module. For some reason it is not working and I can't figure out why. Anyone have any idea why? Thanks so much!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("B1") Then


r1 = Range("B1").Value
Range("A1").Value = 2 * r1

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B1" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A1").Value = 2 * Range("B1").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If this fails to work, but does not produce an error message, you may need to re-enable **Events** .  Put this in a standard module and run it:

```
Sub EventsOn()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kapol, but I am not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in general, compare object references in this way as there's no guarantee that the two ranges that you're comparing are referring to the same `Range` object.

This code is a viable alternative:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then 
    'Continue from here
```

Comment: I had this originally and it didn't work either, which is why I switched to what I have now

Comment: I did and the same thing. Maybe I am missing something on how to execute it? I just have save the script in the worksheet and then go into Excel and change the value of B1. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Is the code in the vba module associated with a particular worksheet? It will only be called due to changes in that worksheet. Else, check that macros are enabled.